# Making one of the slices in a chart.js pie chart thicker?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

Is it possible to make a slice of a chart.js doughnut chart thicker than the rest of the slices?

[For example in this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-behavc?file=index.ts) is it possible to make the blue slice 25% thicker than the purple slice?

This is the code from the demo.

```
const config: ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue'],
    datasets: [
      {
        hoverOffset: 24,
        backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 9, 132)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
        borderWidth: 0,
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [75, 25],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        position: 'nearest',
      },
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 0,
        max: 20,
      },
    },
  },
};
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `borderWith` as an array of values where each value corresponds to a specific slice.

```
borderWidth: [10, 0]
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue'],
    datasets: [{
      hoverOffset: 24,
      backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 9, 132)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      borderWidth: [10, 0],
      hoverBorderColor: 'white',
      label: '# of Points',
      data: [75, 25]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        displayColors: false // hides the colored box polluted by hoverBorderColor
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="200"></canvas>
```